Settings that work for Call Recorder Cube ACR on Google Pixel 8 Pro [no audio is recorded]
For Call Recorder Cube ACR on a Google Pixel 8 Pro, it doesn't seem to work. ie: either no file is recorded at all, or the file has no audio in it.
Which settings work?
On Android 14.
Cube ACR:

https://cubeacr.app/
On Android app store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder&referrer=utm_source%3Dcacr_site

Note: I have also installed and enabled the Cube ACR Helper by following the instructions here: https://cubeacr.app/helper.html
Here are some of my settings:

Showing that the Cube ACR Helper is enabled:



Cube ACR settings:
I've tried "Voice recognition (software)" and "Voice communication (software)" modes. Neither work.




Related research

Seems to indicate that it worked on Android 13 but not on Android 14 now: https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/17bupwo/cube_acr_call_recording_and_android_14/


Uninstalling Automatic Call Recorder and going back to the Voice recognition (software) setting has made it work.
This comment of this Reddit thread indicated that that setting should work, and it does now.
So now call recording works on Android 14 with the Google Pixel 8 Pro via the Cube ACR app + Cube ACR Helper app.
Key takeaway
Call recording does not work with any bluetooth device, but it does work with the normal ear speaker and loudspeaker. So, be sure to disconnect any bluetooth device before recording a call.
This apparently is an unsurmountable limitation due to the restrictions Google has intentionally imposed inside the Android OS itself.
Tests to perform:
Key:

[x] = works / passed
[F] = Failed
[ ] = not tested yet

Cube ACR Setting: Voice recognition (software)
Over normal ear speaker ("Phone", in the Google Google "Phone" app):

[x] Normal outgoing call over cell tower with normal ear speaker: works
[x] Incoming call over WiFi with normal ear speaker: works, but loses the first few seconds of the call (does not record it)
[ ] Incoming call over cell tower (by disconnecting from WiFi) with normal ear speaker: ?

Over loudspeaker ("Speaker", in the Google "Phone" app):

[x] outgoing call over cell tower: works; the other person is louder and clearer than with the normal ear speaker
[ ] incoming call over WiFi: ?
[ ] incoming call over cell tower (WiFi off): ?

Over Bose QuietComfort noise-cancelling headphones connected over Bluetooth

[F] outgoing call over cell tower: fail! It records me but not the other person
[ ] incoming call over WiFi: ?
[ ] incoming call over cell tower (WiFi off): ?

Over Google Pixel Buds Pro noise-cancelling earbuds connected over Bluetooth

[F] outgoing call over cell tower: fail! It records me but not the other person
[ ] incoming call over WiFi: ?
[ ] incoming call over cell tower (WiFi off): ?

So, recording in "Phone" or "Speaker" mode seems to work, but over Bluetooth devices it only records you instead of the person too.
Cube ACR acknowledges this as a limitation of their work-around they found to make the software work at all. See their FAQ: https://cubeacr.app/faq.html:

Can’t hear the interlocutor when on Bluetooth/headset (Android 9-14)
Unfortunately, the fix we found to work around Google's call recording limitations on Android 9-14 will not work for calls using a headset.

Cube ACR Setting: Voice communication (software)
Bose QuietComfort noise-cancelling headphones connected over Bluetooth

[F] outgoing call over WiFi: fail! It records nothing at all

Cube ACR Setting: Voice call (software)
Bose QuietComfort noise-cancelling headphones connected over Bluetooth

[F] outgoing call over WiFi: fail! It records some background fuzz but that's it; no voices from either side

Other Cube ACR notes

They recommend using setting voice communication (software) for Android 9, and voice recognition (software) for Android 10-14. They also sometimes recommend voice call (software).
See their FAQ:

Does Cube ACR app support Android 10/14?
...
Set phone recording audio source to ‘voice recognition (software)’ and increase the recording clarity in the app settings - recording. In the same menu, also enable ‘force in-communication mode’. If this does not help, change the audio source to ‘voice call (software)’ and try again.

and:

The recordings quality is very low
Make sure you have set the correct audio source for the phone calls: ‘voice communication (software)’ ( Android 9)/ 'voice recognition (software)' (Android 10-14).


Bluetooth devices don't work, as mentioned above.


